# Form initialization from ribbon - defaulting to what should be the inactive workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've been building my first VBA database application in Excel. I've created my form - "Frmweeklytimesheet" which captures some inputed data and moves that data to sheet 2 in the same workbook.

I want to be able to open this workbook and initialize the form from the "Ribbon". So I customized the ribbon and added a button which is linked to run the Macro CallTimesheet which opens the workbook - here is the code for this.

```
   Sub CallTimesheet()
Dim FilePath As String
Workbooks.Open "S:\Shanes Stuff\Excel Data Base Stuff\TestDataBase.xlsm"
'Frmweeklytimesheet.Show >> This was moved into the Microsoft Excel Objects folder ThisWorkBook to execute on Open
End Sub
```

I tried to open the form at this point and it didn't work here so the line is commented out for reference.

Thus I moved the form.Show statement to the Microsoft Excel Objects Folder under the following code-

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Frmweeklytimesheet.Show
End Sub
```

So here's my problem - 
This works when I do not have an open work book, I can click / select the button in the ribbon and it all opens / operates as planned. If however, there is another workbook (lets call that "wbk2") open,  it will correctly open the Workbook "TestDataBase.xlsm"  but the Form keeps referencing the "wbk2".

Any suggestions, I'm a new to this so any help is much appreciated.

Tks
S.

Answer (score 0):

With a separate Workbook_Open in each workbook, you should be able to set the owner of the form by referencing the workbook calling the Workbook_Open macro.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    thisworkbook.Frmweeklytimesheet.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: DIdn't want to work, I'm getting a "Method or data member not found" error.

Comment: it looks like to me that it is opening the Form before the workbook has had time to load, so it references the only active spreadsheet at the point in time. Just thought I'll try placing a sheet.activate at the start of the form code and see what that does....

Comment: Found my issue - I had the Workbook_Open macro placed within the worksheet. I moved it out to it's own unique VBA Project and it now works. Is this the correct standard?

Comment: No, but neither does it belong in a worksheet code page. It belongs in the **ThisWorkbook** code page.